# How to get notified when InterstitialAd closes?

Tags: android, interstitial

I was able to build and run a new [InterstitialAd example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/main/java/admob/InterstitialExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/interstitialexample/MyActivity.java) with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0`, but can't figure out how to get notified when InterstitialAd closes?

Previously with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0` I used the following code with `onAdClosed()` handler:

```
                // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
                iAd = new com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd(activity);
                iAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

                iAd.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded()
                    {
                        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                        isLoaded.set(true);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                        onInterstitialAdLoaded();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
                    {
                        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                        hasFailed.set(true);
                        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onAdFailedToLoad code=%d", errorCode));
                        onInterstitialAdFailedToLoad();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdOpened()
                    {
                        // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAdOpened");
                        onInterstitialAdOpened();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClicked()
                    {
                        // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAdClicked");
                        onInterstitialAdClicked();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLeftApplication()
                    {
                        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAdLeftApplication");
                        onInterstitialAdLeftApplication();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed()
                    {
                        // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAdClosed");
                        onInterstitialAdClosed();
                        loadInterstitialAd();
                    }
                });
```

but this `onAdClosed()` does not exist anymore in `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0`.

What is the replacement?

There is [FullScreenContentCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/FullScreenContentCallback) that have `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()` method, for example, but it is not clear what is it for. What does `Called when the ad dismissed full screen content.` mean?

And what should I do with `onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent()`?

Answer (score 2):

Load ad using below code.

```
    InterstitialAd.load(this, "UNI_ID",
                    adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAds) {
                            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                            isLoaded.set(true);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                            onInterstitialAdLoaded(interstitialAds);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                            super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                            hasFailed.set(true);
                            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onAdFailedToLoad code=%d", errorCode));
                            onInterstitialAdFailedToLoad();
                        }
                    });
```

Below code will show your ad that function call inside "onAdLoaded".

```
    private void onInterstitialAdLoaded(InterstitialAd interstitialAds) {
        interstitialAds.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.ads.AdError adError) {
                Log.d(LOG, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: ");
                // Code to be executed when an ad show fails.
                hasFailed.set(true);
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("onAdFailedToLoad code=%d", errorCode));
                onInterstitialAdFailedToLoad();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent();
                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
                Log.d(TAG, "onAdOpened");
                onInterstitialAdOpened();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
                Log.d(TAG, "onAdClosed");
                onInterstitialAdClosed();
                loadInterstitialAd();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                super.onAdClicked();
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
                Log.d(TAG, "onAdClicked");
                onInterstitialAdClicked();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdImpression() {
                super.onAdImpression();
            }
        });
        interstitialAds.show(TestAdActivity.this);
    }
```